# Overriding PHP Class Instantiation

Tags: php, class, object

I'm currently working on a project where we are developing an application that will be used to power content on multiple sites from a single set of files / hosting environment.

There are a number of PHP classes with names such as `model_account` and `model_vehicle` which are defined in seperate files named the save as the class name. We are using `spl_autoload_register` to load the class files as below (simplified):

```
function my_autoloader($class_name) {
    if(substr($class_name, 0, 6)=='model_') {
        require_once('models/'.$class_name.'.php');
    }
}
```

What we want to do, is if the visitor is accessing site xxx and we create an instance of a class, eg `$account = new model_account();` - actually create an instance of class `model_xxx_account` if the file exists (`models/model_xxx_account.php`), but if it doesn't, just include the `models/model_account.php` file and create an instance of `model_account`.

Likewise, if a visitor came from site yyy, we would want to use `model_yyy_account` if exists, but full back to `model_account` if it doesn't.

Essentially what we wish to do is create an instance of a different class if conditions are met, but from the same instantiation call.

We're not using an off-the-shelf framework like CI or Cake. Also, I've slightly simplified the naming conventions for this post. Sorry if my OO terminology isn't spot on.

Comment: I would suggest either namespaces or switching to a factory pattern, anything else will just be a quick and dirty hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually sounds like you should be using some sort of factory pattern to deal with your class loading.

If you do `$account = new SomeClass()`, it does not make any sense to ever really end up with an object of `class Bumblebee`.

You should technically have some sort of account factory that decides which class to give you.

You code will end up looking more like `$account = AccountFactory::retrieveModel()`, which then can determine which model you want to load WITHOUT delegating to your autoloader.

The point of the autoloader is to essentially say "I want THIS exact class", and isn't to be wibbly wobbly or in particular be making any sort of decisions of that sort.  Your factory can actually go through your file structure and determine which class to pass back in the function call, and in your code you aren't relying on `new` to get the model you want, since it seems in theory all of your account models will be sharing the same interface or at least extending `model_account`.

AccountFactory can essentially say, "`model_yyy_account` exists, thus `return new model()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't. The autoloader only helps you selecting a file to include, not allowing you to change the class.

But that shouldn't be a problem. You can just name the classes for each website `model_account`. The site determines which file gets included and thus which version of `model_account` is instantiated. Because you will never (assumption) need both `model_xxx_account` and `model_yyy_account` in a single request, they won't interfere which each other, even if they have the same name.

PS: I would name the files the same as well, and create a separate folder for each site and a folder with defaults. That will make it easier to spot overriden files per site and shrinks the risk of name clashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$SiteID = 'xxx'; // Modify as you wish from your subdomain or whatever
// class_exists triggers the autoloader
if(!class_exists($ClassName =  "model_{$SiteID}_account")){
    // If class is missing, fall back to default
    $ClassName =  "model_account"; // This should exist
}
$Model = new $ClassName(); // Instantiate your Account Model
```

Just make sure **$SiteID** contains _ and alphanumerics hence is class name friendly.

And never do **require_once** from relative paths. Alway do:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/models/'.$class_name.'.php'; // PHP 5.3+
// or
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/models/'.$class_name.'.php'; // PHP 5.2-
```

to stay safe. This way you know exactly where you are seeking the Account Model class.

Answer (score -1):

You can certain do this:

```
$className = "MyClassName";
$myObject = new $className();
```

Where you can dynamically define $className based on what your conditions are.